# In request/etree , `selector.xpath()` return back nothing

Tags: xpath, python-requests, lxml

In below code , `selector.xpath()` return back nothing (the variable `brand` is only `[]`) .
The xpath i checed using `xpath helper`, the result  ok. Anyone can help ? Thanks!

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

    url_us='https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BR3F9N6'
    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36'}
    web=requests.get(url_us,headers=headers)
    selector=etree.HTML(web.text)
    brand=selector.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div[4]/div[4]/div[36]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span')
    brand_name=brand.get_text()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the page source in your browser, you will see the probable cause of your problem. The HTML which your XPath refers to is actually generated by JavaScript code after the page has loaded in your browser. You will have to execute the JavaScript and render the page before you can query it. See https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/index.html?highlight=javascript#javascript-support

Comment: Thanks for your comments,  could your help to give the specific code ? I refered the linkage , but i dn't know how to adjust the code ...